# Break in lines under "ctrl+M" in lyx

Tags: lyx

I am using lyx for quite a time but can't figure out a way to break the equation in two steps when writing under "ctrl+M", as "enter" key doesn't support with "ctrl+M". So, please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you press „ctrl + M“ you are inserting an inline formula. Those formulas are broken automatically. You can use `\allowbreak` to specify additional places where LaTex can break the formula: E.g. LaTex will not break the formula „a,b“, but „a,`\allowbreak` b“ can be broken after the comma.

For larger formulas the display style will probably suit you better. Just press „ctrl + shift + M“ in LyX to enter such formulas. You can use „ctrl + enter“ to insert new lines in these formulas.

Note: You can also use „ctrl + enter“ for inline formulas, but this converts your formula to display style.

Comment: Whenever i'm using "ctrl+enter", it gives me extra line as well as a break up of two lines, how can i avoid the horizental line break up.

Comment: This „horizontal line break“ can be used to align your equations. If you don’t want to align your equations, you can use multline environment (this will left align the first line, right align the last line and center all lines in between) or the gather environment (this will center all lines). Just right-click in the formula and choose AMS Environment → AMS gather environment resp. AMS multline environment from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. Roman has some good points in his answer, but I can add one thing. There is a possibility for using multi-line math environments also in inline math. For example if you want two lines aligned at an equals sign, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and then choose Insert --> Math --> *Aligned Environment*. If you don't need alignment, use *Gathered* instead. It probably won't look that good, but the option is there.